# Custom post type single page returning 404 error when sharing archive url with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I am currently having an issue with my single custom post types returning a 404 error. The thing that is baffling me is that I have set this up exactly the same for another custom post type and it works perfectly. Although it was a good few hours of trial and error and searching forum posts to achieve this for my other custom post type - so I'm not sure if there was something else that I had done that has now been deleted but still helped with setting it up correctly?

**What I am trying to achieve is this permalink structure for my custom post type to be**

- 'news-media' - archive page
- 'news-media/custom-taxonomy' - taxonomy archive page
- 'news-media/custom-taxonomy/name-of-post' - single post page

**Previously I had this set up as**

- 'news-media' - archive page (which is correct)
- 'news-media/custom-taxonomy' - taxonomy archive page (which is correct)
- 'news-media-article/name-of-post'- single post page (this one is incorrect)

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'canvas_cpt_init' );

function canvas_cpt_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'News Media', 'post type general name', 'canvas' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'News Media', 'post type singular name', 'canvas' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'News & Media', 'admin menu', 'canvas' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'News & Media', 'add new on admin bar', 'canvas' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'News Media', 'canvas' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New News Media', 'canvas' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New News Media', 'canvas' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit News Media', 'canvas' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View News Media', 'canvas' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All News & Media', 'canvas' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search News & Media', 'canvas' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent News Media:', 'canvas' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No News & Media found.', 'canvas' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No News & Media found in Trash.', 'canvas' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'news-media/%mediacat%', 'with_front' => false ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => 'news-media',
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author','thumbnail')
    );

    register_post_type( 'newsmedia', $args );

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => __('Categories','canvas'),
        'singular_name'     => __('Category','canvas'),
        'search_items'      => __('Search Categories','canvas'),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories', 'canvas' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category', 'canvas' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category', 'canvas' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category', 'canvas' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name', 'canvas' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'News Category', 'canvas' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'news-media' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'news-media', array( 'newsmedia' ), $args );
}

function wpa_show_permalinks_media( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'newsmedia' ){
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'news-media' );
            if( $terms ){
                    return str_replace( '%mediacat%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
            }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks_media', 10, 2 );
```

*Edit*
I should also mention that I have re-saved the permalinks in the admin dashboard. (On numerous occasions) and still receive a 404 error.
I have also tried swapping the 'has_archive' from true, false and 'news-media' for both the register_post_type and register_taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more research I came across this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698827/custom-permalink-structure-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post-name
 - which I now think I remember using at some point but must have deleted thinking it hadn't worked (as I hadn't figured out the rest of the process). But this is the particular function and filter that worked:

```
/**
 * Tell WordPress how to interpret our project URL structure
 *
 * @param array $rules Existing rewrite rules
 * @return array
 */
function so23698827_add_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
  $new = array();
  $new['news-media/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?newsmedia=$matches[2]';
  $new['news-media/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?news-media=$matches[1]';

  return array_merge( $new, $rules ); // Ensure our rules come first
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'so23698827_add_rewrite_rules' );
```